# Is there a CMS similar to Umbraco, that can accommodate Language as a separate dimension for the content nodes?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

Does Umbraco allow you to add multiple languages, as another dimension for the content nodes?

I have begun to love Umbraco, but recently I was approached by a huge customer from India, where they have multiple languages. So the default support of languages does not work, where each language has its own content tree, rather they would prefer having a single content tree, and be able to change content for each language on the same tree.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't out of the box. But there is a nice package for it, named Vorto: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/vorto/

Comment: As far as I understand, Umbraco is planning on integrating vorto-like features into the core in version 8 as well.

Comment: Yup. But v8 is still quite a while away :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Umbraco-8 was what I needed back then.